# Given a finite list of prime factors, what is the fastest way to find all numbers that can be formed from them

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$$ \text{Let} \ S = \{p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n\} $$
$$ \text{where} \ p_i \in \Bbb P$$

What is the fastest known method method/algorithm to generate all unique numbers through product operation on $S$?

$\text{Ex}: S= \{3,5,2\} $
Soln:
$3\times5 = 15$
$3\times2 = 6$
$3\times5\times2 = 30$
$5\times2 = 10$

Currently, my ideas hover around generating all subsets of $S$, multiplying all the members in each of them and eliminating the duplicates from the list of numbers so generated. This is $O(2^n)$.

Comment: I assume the primes may not be distinct, correct?

Comment: If there are duplicates, $S$ is a multiset.  Let's say $S$ contains $m_j$ copies of $p_j$, where $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ are the distinct members of $S$.  Then the numbers you can form are all of the form $\prod_{j=1}^k p_j^{d_j}$ where $d_j$ are integers, $0 \le d_j \le m_j$.
There are $\prod_{j=1}^k (m_j+1)$ of them.  And it's easy to enumerate them, say in lexicographic order.

Comment: You should realize that in case $S$ has $n$ (distinct) elements, every one of its $2^n$ subsets has a different product, so there are that many elements in your answer. Do you hope to generate them in less than $O(2^n)$ time? That is of course impossible.

Comment: [This book](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/CombAlgDownld.html) by Nijenhuis and Wilf give an algorithm for systematically enumerating subsets. See [this](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/wilf/distrib/processed/) for a FORTRAN implementation of the algorithms in the book.

Comment: @Alex Yes, primes need not be distinct. But ordering is flexible.

Comment: @Robert Will this approach not give $1$ as the answer also? (Which should not be). For example, $5^0 . 3^0 . 2^0$, considering $d_j$ has an inclusive lower bound of $0$

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen AFAIK, It is not known whether that is impossible or even possible ;)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! I will go through the resource and hope to find something worthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example solution I saw a very nice [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92086/for-a-set-such-as-n-1-n-2-ldots-n-k-how-can-i-create-all-combinations) (the answer by @Arturo Magidin) that may be relevant to you.

Answer (score 4):

If the primes are distinct and repetitions (e.g. $3\times3\times 5$) are forbidden, then going through the whole list of subsets will yield no duplicates, because the [fundamental theorem of arithemetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) says prime factorizations are unique.

(If unlimited numbers of repetitions are allowed, you get an infinite list.  It is a somewhat edifying exercise to prove that the sum of the reciprocals of those infinitely many numbers will be finite if you had only finitely many primes in your initial list.)